# Java spring Rest json - ajuda em get passando um json no body

Tags: java, json, api, rest

Preciso consumir um webservices rest em json usando GET e passando um json no body.

Problema:
Criaram um endpoint GET recebendo o parametro no BODY e não na url como de costume.

Eu preciso enviar no body este json:
{"cpf":"06xxx00"}

Usando o Postman eu consegui fazer o teste.
Desculpem a forma como escondi algumas coisas na imagem.. usei um editor online no linux rsrs.
[image: Teste request no postman]

Porém no java não consigo... tentei de uma forma mais "nativa" com HttpURLConnection.
Tentei pelo RestTemplate - getForObject.. porém sem sucesso.
Este é um trecho de código que chegou mais "próximo" do que preciso.. mas sem sucesso

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
headers.add("Authorization", CashBack.token); //aqui ja retorna o formato "Bearer token-gerado"
    
HttpEntity <String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(cpf, headers);
ResponseEntity<CashBack[]> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://urldaaplicacao/gestor.api.integracaozipper/cliente/fidelidade", HttpMethod.GET, entity, CashBack[].class);
```

O erro que aparece é:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnsupportedMediaType: 415 Unsupported Media Type
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:95) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:123) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:785) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:586) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at com.bezkoder.spring.datajpa.controller.ClienteController.salvarCashBack(ClienteController.java:95) ~[classes/:na]
at com.bezkoder.spring.datajpa.controller.ControleTimer.rodar(ControleTimer.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro está faltando um header. Provavelmente o `Content-Type:application/json` . no seu código que monta o request no Java. Você pode confimar verificando os headers incluídos no postman, na imagem que postou dá pra ver que existem 9 headers. Basta só fazer igual no Java que provavelmente vai dar certo.

Comment: Olá, seu código foi formatado para uma melhor aparência. Caso queira, é possível editar a postagem. Para isso basta clicar no botão [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/527399/edit). Também removi mensagens de cumprimentos [saiba o motivo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/38/como-se-portar-ao-perguntar-responder).

Comment: SIm, eu entendi, o problema é que provavelmente o erro agora é outro. Provavelmente após ajustar o header, está recebendo um erro 400.

Comment: Olá @Danizavtz ! muito obrigado por disponibilizar a ajudar. Então o problema é que eu preciso passar este parametro no body da requisição: "{\"cpf\":\"000xxx\"}" Até vou editar a questão e por esta informação que faltou 

PS: tive que apagar o comentario pois estava um CPF de uma pessoa.

PS2 e mais importante: no código eu não estou passando o json com o cpf no body... é exatamente isso que não sei como fazer

Comment: Talvez [isso possa ajudar](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-post-json)

Comment: @Danizavtz muito obrigado, eu vi este artigo ai... mas ele é POST e o que eu preciso é um GET... eu to a 3 dias já pesquisando em vários lugares... e não encontro GET passando JSON no BODY da requisição =(

Até achei um post aqui no stackoverflow sobre boas práticas... mas não encontrei nada que ajudasse.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Answer (score 0):

Eu achei este "problema" muito interessante, por duas razões:

1. É incomum nos dias atuais, com todas as discussões sobre REST, verbos HTTP, maturidade de APIs, que se planeje uma API passando um request body em uma requisição `GET`.
2. Os motivos do `RestTemplate` não funciona como o esperado, e deixar claro uma explicação do problema

Primeiramente vamos para o que diz a [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-24) para amparar meu primeiro ponto:

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

Pelo verbo `GET` se tratar de recuperação de informação, algumas implementações podem ignorar ou rejeitar o corpo da requisição caso enviado.

Mas não se engane, existem várias implementações atualmente que utilizam este verbo passando corpo na requisição, o pessoal do Elasticsearch utiliza muito isso e sempre existem [discussões](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16024) sobre o tema.

Agora vamos para o que realmente interessa, porque o `RestTemplate` não funciona como esperado, e como fazer ele funcionar:

1. O `RestTemplate` utiliza por padrão uma implementação que desconsidera a passagem de um corpo na requisição, em caso do verbo ser `GET`, essa implementação pode ser vista [aqui](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java):

```
    /**
     * Template method for preparing the given {@link HttpURLConnection}.
     * <p>The default implementation prepares the connection for input and output, and sets the HTTP method.
     * @param connection the connection to prepare
     * @param httpMethod the HTTP request method ({@code GET}, {@code POST}, etc.)
     * @throws IOException in case of I/O errors
     */
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) throws IOException {
        if (this.connectTimeout >= 0) {
            connection.setConnectTimeout(this.connectTimeout);
        }
        if (this.readTimeout >= 0) {
            connection.setReadTimeout(this.readTimeout);
        }

        boolean mayWrite =
                ("POST".equals(httpMethod) || "PUT".equals(httpMethod) ||
                        "PATCH".equals(httpMethod) || "DELETE".equals(httpMethod));

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects("GET".equals(httpMethod));
        connection.setDoOutput(mayWrite);
        connection.setRequestMethod(httpMethod);
    }
```

No caso de um GET, a variável `mayWrite` será `false`, logo o `doOutput` também será `false`, não permitindo a escrita no corpo da requisição. Mais detalhes podem ser vistos [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#doOutput).

Para fazer com que esse comportamento funcione, será necessário customizar o `RequestFactory` do `RestTemplate`:

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

@PostConstruct
public void configure() {
  restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new CustomRequestFactory());
}

private static final class CustomRequestFactory extends HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory {
  
  @Override 
  protected HttpUriRequest createHttpUriRequest(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) { 
    return HttpMethod.GET.equals(httpMethod) ? new HttpGetWithRequestBody(uri) : super.createHttpUriRequest(httpMethod, uri);
  }
}

private static final class HttpGetWithRequestBody extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {
  
  public HttpGetWithRequestBody(final URI uri) {
    super.setURI(uri);
  }
  
  @Override
  public String getMethod() {
    return HttpMethod.GET.name();
  }
}
```

A idéia aqui é prover uma implementação que inclua o corpo da requisição para o `GET`, e em caso de outros métodos, siga com a implementação padrão que pode ser vista [aqui](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e9cf645b86c39c66759492435e6d44b70736cee5/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java#L275).